# What features to use from character candidates

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network

I partially implemented [the Stroke Width Transform algorithm](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~turkel/imagepapers/text_detection.pdf).
My implementation is ugly, but something works

My implementation gives me many candidates (I use some rules to filter them). But I still have many non-character candidates.
I want to use neural network (or another ML algorithm) to filter them.

What feature I should use for my classifier?

I can extract mean / std (of SW value of component) and width / height.

Example:

[image]

Red rectangles is character candidates
(Implementation doesn't detect light-on-dark characters, bad detection of "Land Rover" is normal)
SWT image after component filtering

[image]

Comment: It would help a lot if you could include the outputs you get, so we can see which descriptors could be useful. For instance, I have no idea what constitutes your (non-)characters candidates, specially because you mention "My implementation is ugly, but something works". This means it could be producing any kind of output.

Comment: I added one sample. I will add more samples and some info about components later

Comment: That doesn't help much. You will be extracting features based on the result of the SWT transform, right ? So you need to include the resulting image after SWT, not the original image with selected rectangles.

Comment: Maybe you meant this: http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=1219bf2b99370c81999c69cf2bc40978

Comment: That is more likely it, now to make things easier for everyone you could leave only the regions in that image that correspond to the rectangles you are showing in the input image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neural networks and other techniques such as SVM are not used to filter inputs, instead they are used to classify the input. The difference is that filtering will discard an input based on whether they match or not the imposed rules, so it doesn't actually require any training (more likely a handful of good thresholds). A /trained/ classifier, on the other hand, assigns a class to a given input, which means you need to adequately train the classifier with the expected classes as well negative samples. So the approaches vary if you want to do the former or the later, but the features you use in the former might be useful for doing the later too.

Some basic pre-processing for whatever path you take involves first getting a clearer component, by this I mean removing the extraneous white dots inside the components present in the example given. After that, a lot of options are available. The basic width and height measurements can be used to filter the components that are you sure to not match what you expect, so there is no need to classify it either. By considering the skeleton of the connected components, you obtain the end points and branch points, which form two features. The euler number is another one, and, in fact, there are way too many possible features to be extracted to list them all here. The characteristic of these mentioned features is that they are all scale, rotation, and translation invariant. This also means you need another features to distinguish, for example, a `9` from a `6`, the centroids of the holes in the skeleton would be one such example (just take care with it because the direct extraction of this feature isn't invariant to anything).

Note that even simple features can help in separating the entire character set. For instance, for the Euler number = 0, you will get only 'A', 'D', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', '0', '4', '6', or '9', supposing ascii alphanum, a well-behaved font, and a good pre-processing of the input.

Lastly, there is a quite decent amount of papers to look for more info and different approaches beyond SWT. For instance, [T-HOG](http://www-poleia.lip6.fr/~cord/Publications_files/Minetto_PR_T-HOG_draft-1.pdf) is a recent one of them which, according to the published results, is marginally better than SWT.

EDIT: Resuming and extending:

If you want to use machine learning, you will need a good handful of labeled data from which you can separate for training and testing. If your objective is only distinguishing between "this is a character" from "this is not a character", and the later class is not adequately described (i.e., you have few examples of what is not a character, or you cannot characterize it for any kind of input you can receive), One-Class SVM is an option.

For the features to be extracted from the individual characters, as mentioned before, there are too many of them and many approaches to it. The paper "Feature Extraction Methods for Character Recognition -- A Survey" (1995, not recent at all) discusses some of them (it also mentions the expected minimum size of training data, be sure to read it), so I'm including part of its contents here.

Probably good features to extract from the character (both for grayscale and binary image):

- Hu, Reiss, Flusser, Suk, Bamieh, de Figueiredo Moments (all Geometric Moments Invariants based on improvements of the initial work by Hu at "Visual Pattern Recognition by Moment Invariants");
- Zernike Moments

Good features to extract from skeletonized characters:

- Number of T-joints;
- Number of X-joints;
- Number of bend points;
- Number of endpoints;
- Number of crossings with the axis by placing the origin in the shape's centroid;
- Number of semi-circles

Fourier descriptors can also be applied in either the skeleton, the binary representation, or a graph representation of the character as discussed in the mentioned paper.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that's used in practice is to just scale all the candidates to the same dimensions (width x height) and then input each of these pixels into the neural network.

Then you have an output for each character (returning between 0 and 1, for how close of a match it is) (and possibly a last output to indicate no match, though this could be concluded from not having a clear candidate character).

With a neural network, you will need quite a bit of training data, it's simply the way it is. Options to avoid manually getting the required training data:

- Look for training data online
- Generate training data algorithmically (create an algorithm to draw characters and backgrounds and feed them into the NN)
- Perform transformations on already obtained training data (rotate, resize, change colours). This can make a reasonably small training set quite a bit bigger. Make sure not to try to generate too large a percentage of the data this way, otherwise your network probably won't perform well.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But if i use these approach then i need very large number of samples to train ann effectively? Maybe there are more effective approach?

Comment: Does the ratio of positive and negative samples?

Comment: @Dark_Daiver You need a decent amount of both positive and negative samples. I'd say at least `positive:negative = 1:1`. The negative samples can differ a lot more than a given character can, but there are lots of characters, so `1:1` is on average `character:negative = 1:36` (assuming 36 different characters).